# How to provide Return URL Verification with OpenID?

Tags: php, openid

I am using the PHP OpenID library from http://openidenabled.com on my site. However, I just realised I need to support Return URL Verification. How can I do that with this class? I paged through the docs but I couldn't find anything.

Edit: forgot to mention it is a CONSUMER application.

Comment: you mean you will be a provider, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify - it is a consumer application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a blog post that [explains it all](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/06/why-yahoo-says-your-openid-site.html).